# Java Swing Applet - Class not found exception when running appletviewer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet

I designed a JApplet (with Swing) using Netbeans. The class' header looks as follows:

```
public class GUI2 extends javax.swing.JApplet
```

The file P2.jar is generated in P2/dist and I created the following P2.html file. Said file is located in P2/dist, same place as P2.jar

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <applet
            code="GUI2.java"
            width="500"
            height="500">
        </applet>
    </center>

    </body>
</html>
```

I navigate to P2/dist and execute the following command:

```
appletviewer -J"-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy" P2.html
```

*applet.policy* contains the needed permissions to run the applet. I'm getting the following exception after executing:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GUI2.java   at
>   sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:220)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)     at
>   sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:153)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)     at
>   sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:637)     at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:801)     at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:730)    at
>   sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:379)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

After executing, said Applet shows: **applet not initialized**

Comment: `code="GUI2.java"` That would tell the JVM to load a `GUI2.java.class`. Do you see the problem? BTW - applets are dead. Are you using a Java version from this decade?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @AndrewThompson This is a project for university, we are aware it's dead but we have to do it anyway. I tried changing it to code="GUI2" but still the same error.

Comment: *"I tried changing it to code="GUI2"  but still the same error."* What is the package of the applet? What is the structure of the server in relation to the locations of the class file and the HTML loading it? *"This is a project for university, we are aware it's dead but we have to do it anyway."* My commiserations, but note I've given you as much help as I'm willing to expend on a dead technology. Here's one of my copy/paste comments you should take up with the teacher: ..

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).